# bind9 reverse resolution not working

Tags: bind

My forward resolution works and the reverse resolution fails, unable to figure out the problem. I appreciate if someone point the configuration error. Here you go for some files and output

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~$ nslookup 192.168.7.1
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 1.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN



dinesh@ubuntu:~$ nslookup r1.lab.co.in
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   r1.lab.co.in
Address: 1.1.1.1

dinesh@ubuntu:~$ nslookup 2.2.2.2
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 2.2.2.2.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN






dinesh@ubuntu:~$ sudo named-checkzone 168.192.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168 
zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 4
OK
```

**/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.lab.co.in admin.lab.co.in. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; name servers
      IN      NS      ns1.lab.co.in.
      IN      NS      ns2.lab.co.in.

; PTR Records
7.1    IN      PTR     ns1.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.1
7.110   IN      PTR     ns2.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.110
1.1 IN      PTR     r1.lab.co.in.  ; 1.1.1.1
2.2     IN      PTR     r2.lab.co.in.  ; 2.2.2.2
3.3 IN      PTR     r3.lab.co.in.  ; 3.3.3.3
4.4 IN      PTR     r4.lab.co.in.  ; 4.4.4.4
5.5 IN      PTR     r5.lab.co.in.  ; 5.5.5.5
6.6 IN      PTR     r6.lab.co.in.  ; 6.6.6.6
7.7 IN      PTR     r7.lab.co.in.  ; 7.7.7.7
8.8 IN      PTR     r8.lab.co.in.  ; 8.8.8.8
9.9 IN      PTR     r9.lab.co.in.  ; 9.9.9.9
10.10   IN      PTR     r10.lab.co.in.  ; 10.10.10.10
```

**named.conf.options**

```
acl "trusted" {
        192.168.7.1;    # ns1 - can be set to localhost
        192.168.7.10;   #host1

};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
        allow-recursion { trusted; };  # allows recursive queries from "trusted" clients
        listen-on { 192.168.7.1;192.168.7.0/24; };   # ns1 private IP address - listen on private network only
        allow-transfer { none; };      # disable zone transfers by default

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    //forwarders {
    //  8.8.8.8;
    //  8.8.4.4;
    //};

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";


zone "lab.co.in" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab.co.in"; # zone file path
    allow-transfer { 192.168.7.110; };         # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};


zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168";  # 192.168.0.0/16 subnet
    allow-transfer { 192.168.7.110; };  # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};
```

**/var/log/syslog**

```
Feb 27 15:51:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started BIND Domain Name Server.
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: starting BIND 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <id:ebd72b3>
 -f -u bind
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/s
hare/man' '--libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysc
onfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '-
-with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with
-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6
' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--enable-native-pkcs11' '--with-pkcs11=
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-pro
tector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-
null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -
pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DDIG_SIG
CHASE'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: -------------------------------------------
---------
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Co
nsortium,
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-b
enefit
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND
 9 are
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: -------------------------------------------
---------
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1
048576
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: using 2 UDP listeners per interface
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: using up to 4096 sockets
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named
.conf'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/e
tc/bind/bind.keys'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv4) (type 1) 
DB
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv6) (type 12)
 DB
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: initializing GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 2) DB
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 30) DB not availabl
e
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 31) DB not availabl
e
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP Region (type 3) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP Region (type 7) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP ISP (type 4) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP Org (type 5) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: initializing GeoIP AS (type 9) DB
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP Domain (type 11) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: GeoIP NetSpeed (type 10) DB not available
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 
60999]
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 
60999]
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: listening on IPv4 interface tap0, 192.168.7
.1#53
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: sizing zone task pool based on 7 zones
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: using built-in root key for view _default
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: set up managed keys zone for view _default,
 file 'managed-keys.bind'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 16.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 17.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 18.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 19.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 20.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 21.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 22.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 23.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 24.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 25.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 26.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 27.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 28.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 29.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 31.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 64.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 65.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 66.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 67.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 68.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 69.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 70.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 71.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 72.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 73.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 74.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 75.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 76.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 77.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 78.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 79.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 80.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 81.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 82.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 83.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 84.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 85.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 86.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 87.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 88.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 89.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 90.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 91.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 92.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 93.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 94.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 95.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 96.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 97.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 98.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 99.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 100.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 101.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 102.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 103.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 104.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 105.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 106.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 107.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 108.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 109.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 110.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 111.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 112.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 113.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 114.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 115.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 116.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 117.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 118.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 119.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 120.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 121.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 122.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 123.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 124.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 125.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 126.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 127.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.AR
PA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARP
A
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-AD
DR.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0
.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0
.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.A
RPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: automatic empty zone: EMPTY.AS112.ARPA
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind
/rndc.key'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind
/rndc.key'
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: managed-keys-zone: journal file is out of d
ate: removing journal file
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 92
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial
 4
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone lab.co.in/IN: loaded serial 3
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: all zones loaded
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: running
Feb 27 15:51:29 ubuntu named[12665]: zone lab.co.in/IN: sending notifies (serial
 3)
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I edited my post. When I do nslookup for 2.2.2.2, I expect r2.lab.co.in. But i do not get that resolution.

Comment: You don't have a reverse zone for that address!

Comment: If so, why the reverse resolution fails for 192.168.7.1 also. The output updated in the original post

Comment: I think you have probably mistyped something. But what that is, we have no idea. I do not think that what is in your post corresponds to the actual zone files you are using nor the actual commands you have tried. We always recommend [to not use fake information in your posts](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632).

Comment: The files are not manipulated, it is actual. I do not know what makes you to think the /etc/zones/db.192.168 is not actual.Moreover, the commands are executed from my CLI.

Comment: included name.conf.options and local

Comment: Any fatal errors or findings to make it work ???

Comment: I find it interesting that your logs and `named-checkzone 168.192.in-addr.arpa`  both return a serial number of 4 *`168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 4`* but the file you posted has a serial of `3`. It might be a typo but in your question you show the contents of `/etc/zones/db.192.168` and your named.conf references `/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168` in an additional bind subdirectory.

Comment: I guess,  I messed up the serial number. Please clarify going back and forth of serial number is no allowed? What is the significance of serial number ? Actually the title /etc/zones/db.192.168 is typo, the file location is /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168. Please let me know how to clean up the mess i made in the configuration files.

Comment: Besides the serial number issue (which may be more with your question than with what BIND is seeing), `7.1 IN PTR ns1.lab.co.in. ; 192.168.7.1` is lying to you. To `7.1` is appended the origin which by default is the zone name so `168.192.in-addr.arpa`. Thus `7.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` which is the reverse record for 192.168.1.7, but you are looking up 192.168.7.1. See the difference? nslookup is even telling you as much: `server can't find 1.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. In reverse records, you have to reverse the order of the IP address octets: 192.168.7.1 becomes 1.7.168.192 in in-addr.arpa.

Comment: Just for fun, try looking up `192.168.1.7` without making any other changes to your setup, and show us what comes back. I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if you get `ns1.lab.co.in.` back.

Comment: And add 127.0.0.1 to listen-on section of named configuration file.

Comment: Michael.. you nailed the error. However, I completely reworked the files. it works now. Now I could notice the difference in my earlier reverse zone file and now ( as pointed by you). Thanks a lot guys for the quick response. I will update the new file now.

Comment: Thread updated with Working configuration files now.

Comment: @DineshKalidassan Please post the answer as an answer, rather than working it into the question, and accept it (or whichever answer is best). Otherwise the site will not know the question has been answered.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy A name server isn't obligated to listen on all its interfaces, though admittedly, `192.168.7.1;192.168.7.0/24;` is somewhat redundant as the latter also covers the former. It's obviously not a problem, however; BIND is doing what is expected, here.

Comment: @DineshKalidassan I support Hakan's point, and have in fact rolled back those changes.  You should accept Michael's answer below by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it; then everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we determined in the comments, your problem was that your reverse zone did not contain the data you thought it contained. You also had some kind of serial number issue, where you showed us zones with serial number 3 but zone checks and zone load logs for serial number 4.

When you tried to look up the reverse record for 192.168.7.1:

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~$ nslookup 192.168.7.1
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 1.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

the DNS server said "no such record exists". Notice that the address it is attempting to look up (a PTR RR for) is `1.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. So let's compare this to what you have configured your DNS server for.

You have a zone `168.192.in-addr.arpa` so there is a place for anything below that. Let's look at what you are serving in that zone.

```
7.1    IN      PTR     ns1.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.1
```

The default origin for a zone file is the zone name, and the origin is appended to any non-fully-qualified (where "fully qualified" means "terminated by a final period") names in that zone. (This is very useful particularly for forward zones, as it allows you to use the same zone file for lots of similar zones.) So the above is the same thing as:

```
7.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR  ns1.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.1
```

7.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa is the reverse record location for 192.168.1.7, *not* 192.168.7.1. *In reverse DNS zones, the order of all IP address octets are reversed.* This can be a significant source of confusion when you have multi-octet reverse DNS zones. **The comment is lying to you.**

As I suggested in the comments, the way to determine that this is the problem is to simply look up the address that you are *actually* serving a reverse record for, namely 192.168.1.7, and see if that shows the name that you expect for 192.168.7.1. As it apparently did, the solution is to fix your reverse zone by reversing the octet order. In other words, you need to change the reverse zone file to say instead:

```
1.7    IN      PTR     ns1.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.1
```

Once you do that, and increase the zone (SOA) serial number to a value higher than that on any of the slaves (in your case, that's just one), or otherwise force a refresh of the zone on all the slaves, reverse lookups for 192.168.7.1 should yield the expected result `ns1.lab.co.in.`.